# How to know the current UITableView cell position with respect to the UIViewController in swift 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, swift

How to know the current UITableView cell position with respect to the UIViewController in swift 3.0? In my case i m using a label on UITableViewCell with UITapGesture as per my requirement in Swift.

Comment: are you want to the x and y position of cell ?

Comment: "position" is really vague. What exactly do you want?

Comment: want to know the y-axis

Answer (score 5):

This is done easily with `convert(_ rect: CGRect, from view: UIView?)`. See more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622498-convert). So based on that, you can try this:

```
let rect = view.convert(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath), from: tableView)
```

Where `view` is your `viewController`'s view and `tableView` is the table view containing the cell.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
YOURCell.convert(YOURCell.frame, to:YOURUIViewController.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know position (x,y) for cell?
We can get CGRect of cell with indexPath.

```
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: this will return the position of cell in tableView's scroll. and Sunil kr singh wants the position of cell in the UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use the following, assuming `tableView` is the table view containing the cell that you want to get the position of:

```
tableView.convert(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath), to: self.view)
```

I have tested this using Swift 4 and iOS 11.3